# In Phonogram: The Singles Club, is the barmaid Marc's ex-girlfriend?

Tags: phonogram

I've read Kieron Gillen's *Phonogram: The Singles Club* several times, and I simply can't interpret whether the barmaid is supposed to be Marc's ex-girlfriend or not. While the ex appears prominently throughout issue #2 (Marc's story) in ghost/flashback form, the current-day barmaid only appears fully on-panel once: in issue #5, p. 6 (Laura's story).

Arguments for their being the same:

- The barmaid & Marc's ex have an almost identical haircut and color, facial and body shape, eyes and eyebrows, and very similar facial piercings.

Arguments for their being different:

- The barmaid also has tattoos (at least the neck one) which the ex didn't have (although they could be new in the few months since they were together).
- None of the characters (Penny, Laura, Lloyd) comment on the ex being there, even though they're all hyper-aware that Marc's been away because of the breakup.
- In particular, in the panel where the barmaid is fully shown, Laura comments "This is not her music, people or life. This is just her job", which seems contradictory to the ex-girlfriend being a regular at the club.
- Marc seems genuinely happy and lighthearted at the moment he's ordering drinks from her, whereas a short time later when he recalls his ex he's completely devastated.

So: Is the barmaid supposed to be Marc's ex-girlfriend, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is most likely "not the ex-girlfriend". I got this response from the author Kieron Gillen on Twitter:

[image: Kieron Gillen: "I'd normally leave stuff to interpretation, but I suspect we'd have explicitly said something when they interacted if she were."]